# How do I return a key value by providing another key value in a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php

Assume I have an array like the one below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [town_id] => 1
            [town_name] => ABC
            [town_province_id] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [town_id] => 2
            [town_name] => DEF
            [town_province_id] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [town_id] => 3
            [town_name] => GHI
            [town_province_id] => 2
        )
    )
```

I want to provide value "DEF" in the above array and return value "2".

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array` to get your result.

```
$input = 'DEF';
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($input,$value)){
          $town_id = $value['town_id'];
    }
}
print_r($town_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$key = array_search('DEF', array_column($array, 'town_name'));
```

Example:

```
$data = array( array('town_id' => 1, 'town_name' => 'ABC'), array('town_id' => 2, 'town_name' => 'DEF') );
print_r($data);

$key = array_search('DEF', array_column($data, 'town_name'));

print_r($data[$key]['town_id']); // it will have 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_search` and `array_column`

```
$key = array_search('DEF', array_column($your_arr, 'town_name'));

$your_arr[$key]['town_id']; // should return DEF
```

Note: `array_column` works from  PHP 5 >= 5.5.0